# How do I find the name of a target DLL or DSO from qmake?

Tags: qmake

I'm using Qt 4.7.3.  None of the QMAKE_TARGET or TARGET_x.y.z variables are defined. (Is the documentation wrong?)  I'm using the following workaround at the moment:

Linux:

```
$${QMAKE_PREFIX_SHLIB}$${TARGET}.so.$${VER_MAJ}.$${VER_MIN}.$${VER_PAT}
```

Darwin:

```
$${QMAKE_PREFIX_SHLIB}$${TARGET}.$${VER_MAJ}.$${VER_MIN}.$${VER_PAT}.$${QMAKE_EXTENSION_SHLIB}
```

I want the string 'libName.so.1.2.3' on Linux, and 'libName.1.2.3.dylib' on OS X.  These names are generated by qmake for the final product of a project, but there doesn't seem to be a single variable that contains these complete names, even though Qt's documentation implies there should be.

Comment: Without seeing things in context it's hard to say what is happening.  Do you have a short example?

Comment: Edited to show example output.

Comment: Were are you trying to use QMAKE_TARGET in the context of your qmake file.  Is it after `TEMPLATE=lib` and `TARGET=Name` ?

Comment: Yes, the TEMPLATE=lib and the TARGET is defined and works correctly for the example expressions in the Question.